# How to randomly sample and keep only n values of repeating IDs?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sample

I have a data frame that looks like this:

| user_id | tweet_id | tweet |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user123 | 7658j | dogs are super |
| user245 | 66721 | yes dogs are super |
| user245 | 6d343 | yes cats are also super |
| <...> | <...> | <...> |
| user245 | 541238 | well I developed allergy on cates |

As I check value counts for each user, I have the following results:

| id | count |
| --- | --- |
| user245 | 456 |
| user123 | 115 |
| user427 | 2 |

I want to subset the data this way that I keep all rows of ids with value counts below 100, and keep 100 randomly sampled rows of the rows with ids where value counts is above 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
(df.groupby('user_id', group_keys=False)
   .apply(lambda g: g.sample(n=min(len(g), 100)))
)
```

Example (with n=3):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': list('AAAAAABBCDDDD'), 'col': range(13)})
(df.groupby('id', group_keys=False)
   .apply(lambda g: g.sample(n=min(len(g), 3)))
)
```

Output:

```
   id  col
0   A    0
4   A    4
3   A    3
7   B    7
6   B    6
8   C    8
12  D   12
11  D   11
9   D    9
```